# Why is the composite check digit in a machine readable zone of a modern passport not taking into account all of the data?

Tags: passport.js, ocr, checksum, specifications

Modern passports and ID cards have a [machine-readable zone (MRZ)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine-readable_passport) at their bottom, which contains the basic identification information in what presumably is an OCR-friendly format.

The format for the MRZ specifies a number of [check digits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Check_digit), which serve to help detect recognition errors. For example, there is a check digit computed over the number of the document, a check digit covering the birth date, etc.

At the end there is also a "composite check digit", which is computed over the lower row of the record, thus providing a more general overall integrity check.

The "upper row" of the record, which contains the name and surname is, however, not covered by any check digits, which means there is no way at all to catch errors there or verify the correctness of the scan.

My question is the following: is there any reasonable explanation for why this choice was made in the specification? Why wouldn't the specification provide at least a single check digit covering the whole of the data in the record, facilitating the very same "machine-readability" it is aimed at? The standard is mature and widely used, hence this cannot be just a mistake, right?

I understand this question is somewhat unconventional, yet I have no idea where could I go to find the answer - suggestions welcome alongside actual answers.

Comment: Note that there are only check digits for data that will be unchanged: date of birth, document ID, expiry date. Check digits are just redundancy checks, and they do take up space, so you make a trade-off. I think if you can scan the passport ID and expiry date correctly, you should be able to look up the rest from a database easily.

Comment: But if you have a redundancy check up there anyway, why wouldn't you include *all* of the data into it? Why just one row, leaving the name untouched?

Comment: Some things like change of address results in crossing out the old one and panning in a new one. That might apply to names in some places, so check-summing only the information that requires a new passport if changed or just can't be changes is logical. also it makes it more robust, one dent/scratch could invalidate the whole thing so minimize the check to the vitals.

Comment: Well, the change of a name would certainly require a new passport yet the name is not checksummed. The vitals are additionally checksummed anyway (there are separate check digits for number, birth date and date of expiry). The logic with the dents might be plausible (as well as the idea that "most readers could only deal with just one row at the time), but it would still be nice to find some explicit rationale somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

I got curious and went (cursorily) though the actual ICAO 9303 documents which define how the machine-readable zone works, and found no rationale. The most interesting thing is that, though there is discussion about different document formats where a MRZ could appear (like a credit card), the name line seems to always be check-digit-free – if at all present!

So I would venture that one possible reason is that the mapping from "real name" to machine-readable name is lossy, AND seems to not be really standardized, so it [depends on the transliteration rules in each country](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine-readable_passport#Different_spellings_of_the_same_name_within_the_same_document). Meaning that a "real name" converted to machine-readable in country A and then read back in country B might legally get something different than the original "real name". That makes the machine-readable name advisory at best; doesn't sound like it makes much sense to give it a check digit anyway. Meanwhile, the checksummed data can be contrasted visually, since it seems to be standardized to use arabic digits.

Add to that the [typical problems when trying to canonicalize names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/), and maybe you'd also end up deciding that it's better to allow for some leeway.

As a side note, I just realized that each of the 3 debit cards I have (from the same country!) has my name slightly differently. If I had to check programmatically that those names are all the same, I would certainly make the thing fuzzy, and then I don't think I'd care (much?) about a check digit.

A further side note: my obviously alien name in the country where I live always makes for "interesting" situations when dealing with official paperwork. I don't think I have ever managed to have it properly written down in here; but luckily it doesn't matter. The moment that any official, nurse, doctor, HR, whoever hears that I have an official ID number, they just sigh with relief and stop caring about getting the name right. (It's also a relief for me!)

So, in summary: the number is needed, and you better get it right. The name is a convenience.

Comment: I understand that the names can be transliterated differently, but it is already transliterated on the MRZ, and there is a unique valid way to compute a valid check digit for *that* transliteration. When I read data off a MRZ that particular transliteration is what I am interested in, after all.

Comment: @KT You are correct in your observation with regards to the transliteration. But there is a character count limit in the visual rendering of the letters such that a truncation is imminent. Therefore, it is in-appropriate and misleading to attach any form of precision protection to a piece of data that cannot be precisely rendered.

Comment: I don't see how adding protection to the truncated & transliterated version of the name encoded on the MRZ is "inappropriate and misleading". This specific version of the name should be encoded precisely and any losses in precision in that piece of data are just as detrimental to user experience as losses in precision in, for example, birth dates.

Comment: The **MRZ** algorithm cannot fully protect and there are edge cases. Take for example this MRZ https://gist.github.com/typelogic/3d203322a39f8df9400a400b74d30cfc , an OCR read for the `doc#` value of either `0012345678` or `OO12345678` will pass all check digits calculation.

Answer (score 2):

To create the key (BAC) to access the RFID data stored on the passport you need document number, date of birth and document expiration date. These numbers are then very important to read without errors. When you have calculated the correct key you can transfer the full name, picture and other data from the RFID chip, with the correct spelling.

Comment: I suspect the MRZ standard appeared way before the RFID chips in the passports, hence the rationale for not-checksumming the name should have been something else.